# User form combo box size - VBA

Tags: excel, vba, combobox, userform

I have a user form which includes many combo boxes and i m wondering if there is a way to decrease the size of each line in a drop down list.  As you can see in the image below the size of the row are very big in comparison with the word size and the top part of the combo box. after change `Listwidth` property a scroll bar appears in the combo box.

Combo box values are imported using loop. Any suggestions?

**Combo Box**

[image: vh]

**After changing Listwidth propert**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.ListWidth` property. The units it uses are `pt`.

You can either set this at design time in the properties pane, or at run-time using code:

```
ComboBox1.ListWidth = 20
```

You can also change the `.ColumnWidths` property if you do not want the horizontal scrollbar to display.

Comment: `ListWidth` does not work. See my edited question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you also adjust the `ColumnWidths` property?

Comment: By change both `ListWidth` & `ColumnWidths` it seems to work.

Comment: Another quick question, is there a way to center align the values of the drop down list?

Comment: You can use the `TextAlign` property for that.